# How to remove curse?

Tags: allah, curse

I cursed someone out of my mind. Now I regret doing so.I want to ask forgiveness from Allah and I want to remove the curse from those person. How can I do that?

Comment: Thinking bad about someone wont put a curse on them. Ask Allah for forgiveness and if you want talk to the person and try to apologise if you acted in a poor manner towards them.

Comment: Please use meaningful question title and relevant tags.

Answer (score 0):

You can make dua to Allah for that person so that Allah forgives all of his sins, brother.

Answer (score 0):

> I cursed someone out of my mind. Now I regret doing so.I want to ask
> forgiveness from Allah and I want to remove the curse from those
> person.How can I do that?

As much as I know/conjecture, by regretting or Istiqfar it will be removed/solved; God willing.

But, three relevant matters:

firstly, if I'm not mistaken: totally, Islam prefer to forgive instead of La'n (cursing)
secondly, According to Imam Ja'far-al-Sadeq: ... the curse will be come back to the one who do curse in some condition(s); e.g. if he/she is not deserved of it, or ...
thirdly, I found an interesting related sentence(s), it remarks: ... we ask Allah for X/Y to be led into the right way (if is feasible), otherwise Allah damn it! instead of a direct La'n which we are not sure if s/he deserves of it or not!

Reference: https://www.yjc.ir/fa/news/6420648/